# Design my Windows Store App in Portrait even when the device is tilted to Landscape

Tags: windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I am a Windows Phone developer and just started with Windows Store Apps. I want my app to only work in Portrait Mode even when the device is tilted to Landscape (I don't want the app to change to landscape mode). How can I set my Windows Store app up to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the app manifest, you can set the supported rotations:

[image]

That said you may have an issue in certification as a result, since [snapped mode is a requirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx#ACR_3_6).  Snapped mode applies to landscape orientation, so it would seem to be something you wouldn't need to do, but as [this thread suggests](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/6164729b-cfa8-48fe-baeb-41a88df07cf8), you may have an issue.  A possible workaround would be to provide a nominal landscape view that simply says the app runs only in portrait mode, but I would heavily document your rationale for supporting only portrait in the "Notes to Testers" when you submit your app to the store.

Comment: Its not working in the simulator.While changing the orientation on simulator the App also changing its Orientations.Plz give a piece of code to set my application in Potrait mode default even the orientation changes in the device or simulator.

Comment: correct, it won't work in the simulator because the mechanism relies on the accelerometer on the device to indicate the orientation change.  There's more additional information in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/11/04/microsoft-windows-simulator-rotation-and-resolution-emulation.aspx) if you're keen on having it work in the simulator, but you'll be fine on the actual device.